# Two submission forms with form-tag on same page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a weekly time entry form currently.  How can i have another time entry form on the same page ? and these two forms need be submitted separately as different records. Any help would be appreciated .

Here is my code:-

**show_weeks.html.erb**

```
 <div class="table-responisve>
  <% if @dates != nil %>

 <table class="table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <% @dates.each do |date| %>
      <th><%=date.to_s+","+date.strftime("%A").to_s %> </th>
   <% end %>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <% @dates.each do |date| %>
      <% if @time_entry %>
        <td><%= text_field_tag "#{date}", @time_entry.hour_per_day["#{date}"], class: "dates" %></td>
      <% else %>
      <%if date < Date.today %> 
              <td> <%= text_field_tag "#{date}", "", class: "dates" %> </td>
      <%else %>   
                <td><%= text_field_tag "#{date}", "", class: "dates" if date == Date.today && Time.now.strftime("%H").to_i >= 10 %> </td>        
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
     <% end %>

  </tr>


  <tr>
    <% if @time_entry %>
     <td colspan="2"> Please Enter your Comment </td>

    <td colspan="5">
        <% @time_entry.comments.each do |c| %>
          <p><%= text_field_tag "Comment", c.message %> </p> 
        <% end %>
      </td>

    <%else%>
    <td colspan="2"> Please Enter your Comment </td>

    <td colspan="5"><%= text_field_tag "Comment", "" %>

    </td>
    <%end%>
  </tr>

</tbody>
 </table>
 </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
   id="save_entries">Submit</button>
  <%= form_tag save_time_entries_path, method: 'post',   
  id:"save_time_entries" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "start_date", @dates.first%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "end_date", @dates.last%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "total_hours", "" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "project_id", @project.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "time_entry", "" %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag "message", "" %>
  <% if @time_entry%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "time_entry_detail_id", @time_entry.id  %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>

  <script>
   $("#save_entries").click(function(){
   var time_entry = []
    var hours = 0;
    var message = document.getElementById("Comment").value;
    $('.dates').each(function() {
      hours += Number($(this).val());
      if ($(this).val() == 0)
      {
      time_entry.push($(this).attr('name'),0)
      }else{
       time_entry.push($(this).attr('name'),$(this).val()) 
      }

  });
  if (hours > 60) {
    alert("Total Hours Should be equal to 60");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    $("#message").val(message);
    $("#time_entry").val(time_entry);
    $("#total_hours").val(hours);
    $("#save_time_entries").submit();
   }
   })
  </script>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out solution. Using of two submission forms on same page is bad idea. So I have create previous weeks records by using after create call back and i given default values for TimeEntryDetail. Here it creates all weeks records in background. Suppose if you skipped for 6 weeks , it'll create 6 empty records in background. Here is my working code

```
Modal.rb

after_create :chceck_time




  def check_time


    @project_mem_check= ProjectMember.where(project_id: project, member_id: user).first.created_at
    #present week dates coming here |
    @time_entry_check = TimeEntryDetail.where(project_id: project, user_id: user).first.created_at 


    if @time_entry_check.nil?
         @time_entry_check=@project_mem_check
    end

    @last_week_start=Date.today.beginning_of_week
    @last_week_end  =Date.today.end_of_week

#cheking project member creation shall be less than time entry creation of that project.
 if    @project_mem_check <= @time_entry_check 

    @time_check_first=TimeEntryDetail.where(project_id: project, user_id: user).pluck(:start_date).first.to_date
    @time_check_last =TimeEntryDetail.where(project_id: project, user_id: user).pluck(:start_date).last.to_date
    #check first entry == last time entry
    if @time_check_first==@time_check_last

       pm=ProjectMember.where(project_id: project, member_id: user).first.created_at.to_date
       tm=Date.today.to_date

       unfilled_weeks= ((tm-pm)/7).to_i+1



       unfilled_weeks.times {

                    @last_week_start= @last_week_start-7
                    @last_week_end  = @last_week_end-7



                    @call_back_entry=TimeEntryDetail.create(start_date: (@last_week_start).to_date, end_date: (@last_week_end).to_date,
                    project_id: project.id, user_id: user.id, hours: 0, aasm_state: "pending", hour_per_day: "" )

                   @call_back_entry.comments << Comment.create(message: "Please fill the timesheet ")

       }

    else

       #Already this user have time entries and create empty records from where he stopped.

       pm=created_at.to_date  #--.present time entry is coming
       tm=Date.today.to_date

       unfilled_weeks= ((tm-pm)/7).to_i+1



       unfilled_weeks.times{

                    @last_week_start= @last_week_start-7
                    @last_week_end  = @last_week_end-7

                  @call_back_entry=TimeEntryDetail.create(start_date: (@last_week_start).to_date, end_date: (@last_week_end).to_date,
                    project_id: project.id, user_id: user.id, hours: 0, aasm_state: "submitted", hour_per_day: "" )

                   @call_back_entry.comments << Comment.create(message: "Not yet filled this week ")


      } 

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 different forms with form_for, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Here, I'm calculating total hours of week. so i need to do this using form_tag only. Any pointers how to do this using form_tag

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

but conceptually is like writing the form tag on your own, it's just something that will prevent you from mistyping

Comment: checked this documentation already. Not so much helpful. Thanks for your prompt

Comment: the form tag is just a tag like if you where writing <form> etc... so you can also write the html code by hand